# Is there a Taos hum?

Tags: sound

I have been dipping in and out of this one over the years....

> Seems the hum was first brought to public attention in 1992 by Taos
>   residents who claimed they'd been hearing it for more than a year.
>   Nine of 12 locals contacted by the paper said they'd heard it. The hum
>   was said to sound like the distant idling of a diesel truck (a low
>   rumble, in other words), and was very annoying. Theories about its
>   source included "UFOs, spiritual rebirth, faulty sewage plants, secret
>   underground mining, high-voltage power lines, and weapons
>   testing."[source](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1297/whats-the-story-with-the-taos-hum)

In the 1990's the consistent low-frequency hum began to be reported by some, but not all residents of Taos, New Mexico.  A [variety of theories](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGHe7rdq0Ds) continue to be put forward as to its origin, and of course, numerous unverified [amateur recordings](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuRBM0i8mbI) of widely varying quality exist, but as yet it remains unexplained (at least to my current googlings).

> The essential element that defines the Hum is what is perceived as a
>   persistent low-frequency sound, often described as being comparable to
>   that of a distant diesel engine idling, or to some similar low-pitched
>   sound for which obvious sources (e.g., household appliances, traffic
>   noise, etc.) have been ruled out. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hum)

I did however find an appropriately skeptical-ish viewpoint from [The Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1297/whats-the-story-with-the-taos-hum):

> A survey of 7,000 Taos-area residents found that only 2 percent had
>   heard it. You're thinking: you could probably find 2 percent who think
>   they've got microchips implanted in their brains! Hmm.
>   Hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm. Sorry, thought I heard something.
>
> Anyway, UNM hearing researcher James Kelly tells me they've done
>   enough investigation to know this is more than just wacky Taos
>   residents eating funny mushrooms. For one thing, tests show all the
>   hum hearers hear pretty much the same low-frequency tone, making it
>   unlikely they're imagining it or suffering from ordinary tinnitus.
>   Research continues. Sure, it's all in their heads. The question is,
>   what's "it"?

**- Is this a case of media hype, mass delusion, or is it a real,
   scientifically explainable phenomenon?**

Answer (score 7):

It's a scientifically studied, yet not fully explained phenomenon which affects around 2% of population around specific foci. There's is a good review of studies on low frequency noise which dedicates a full chapter to "The HUM" and its effect

> 11. The HUM
>
> 11.1 Occurrence.
>
> The Hum is the name given to a low frequency noise which is causing persistent complaints, but often cannot be traced to
> a single, or any, source. If a source is located, the problem moves
> into the category of engineering noise control and is no longer "the
> Hum", although there may be a long period between first complaint and
> final solution. The Hum is widespread, affecting scattered
> individuals, but periodically a Hum focus arises where there are
> multiple complaints within a town or area. There has been the Bristol
> Hum (England), Largs Hum (Scotland), Copenhagen Hum (Denmark),
> Vancouver Hum (Canada), Taos Hum (New Mexico USA), Kokomo Hum (Indiana
> USA) etc. A feature of these Hums is that they have been publicised in
> local and national press, so gathering a momentum which otherwise
> might not have occurred.

[A Review of Published Research on  Low Frequency Noise and its Effects](http://westminsterresearch.wmin.ac.uk/4141/1/Benton_2003.pdf) -- Report for Defra by Dr Geoff Leventhall

So to answer your question: yes, there is a scientifically known phenomenon called the "Taos HUM", but it is not necessarily a real sound -- it is only measured by its health consequences, which are certainly real.